# Show that $\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\beta\right)+\frac{1+\cot\beta}{1-\cot\beta}=-2\tan2\beta$

Tags: geometry

Show that $$\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\beta\right)+\dfrac{1+\cot\beta}{1-\cot\beta}=-2\tan2\beta$$
I'm supposed to solve this problem only with sum and difference formulas (identities).

So the LHS is $$\dfrac{\cot\dfrac{\pi}{4}\cot\beta-1}{\cot\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\cot\beta}+\dfrac{1+\cot\beta}{1-\cot\beta}=\dfrac{\cot\beta-1}{1+\cot\beta}+\dfrac{1+\cot\beta}{1-\cot\beta}=\dfrac{4\cot\beta}{1-\cot^2\beta}$$ I also tried to work with $\sin\beta$ and $\cos\beta$ and arrived at $$\dfrac{4\sin\beta\cos\beta}{\sin^2\beta-\cos^2\beta}$$ I don't see how to get $-2\tan2\beta$ from here (even with other identities).

Comment: Hint: $\tan 2\beta=\tan(\beta+\beta)$

Comment: $\sin(2\beta)=2\sin(\beta)\cos(\beta)$ and $\cos(2\beta)=\cos^2(\beta)-\sin^2(\beta)$

Comment: You are very, very close, use the identities that @user170231 gave for $\sin 2\theta$ and $\cos 2\theta$. You'll have to manage a minus sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{4 \sin \beta \cos \beta}{\sin ^{2} \beta-\cos ^{2} \beta} = \frac{2 \sin2\beta}{-(\cos ^{2} \beta-\sin ^{2} \beta)}=-2\frac{\sin  2\beta}{\cos  2\beta}=-2 \tan(2\beta)$$

Answer (score 2):

The alternative approach is to stay with your original approach and complete it.

$\displaystyle \frac{4\cot\beta}{1-\cot^2\beta}
= \frac{\frac{4}{\tan(\beta)}}{1 - \frac{1}{\tan^2(\beta)}}
= \frac{\frac{4}{\tan(\beta)}}{\frac{\tan^2(\beta) - 1}{\tan^2(\beta)}}
$

$\displaystyle = ~\frac{4\tan(\beta)}{\tan^2(\beta) - 1}
= (-2) \times \frac{2\tan(\beta)}{1 - \tan^2(\beta)} = (-2) \times \tan(2\beta).$